# on submit button click the status code not found in zend php

Tags: php, zend-framework

i am new to php and zend framework, pls help me to solve this problem.

i am trying to construct a registration form using zend, on click of the submit button the control go's to the action but $this->_request->isPost() returns false and status code not found is seen when checked in the network option of the crome browser.

controller

```
public function firstAction()
    {   
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        //die("inside first");

        Zend_Debug::dump($this->_request->isPost());
        //Zend_Debug::dump($indexForm->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()));


        //send the url after the form action
        $options =array("actionUrl"=>'/index/first',"header"=>'test');       

        //connecting the form and the view 
        $indexForm2 = new Application_Form_Login($options);

        //$page = $this->_request->getParam('page');


        if(($this->getRequest()->isPost())){ 
            if ($indexForm2->isValid($request->getPost()))
            {
                $regvalues=$this->getAllParams();               
                $modleinsert= new Application_Model_First(); //Create a modele object               
                $testreg= $modleinsert->getRegInsert($regvalues); 
                $testreg=1;
                if($testreg)
                {
                    $_SESSION['echo'] = "Saved successfully";   
                }
                else 
                {
                    $_SESSION['echo'] = "Please try again";
                }   
        }
        }

        $this->view->indexForm2 = $indexForm2;  
    }
```

FORM CODE

```
<?php

class Application_Form_Login extends Zend_Form
{

   public function init($options=NULL) 
    {
        //form
        $this->setAttrib("horizontal", true);
        $this->removeDecorator("DtDdWrapper");
        $this->setAction($options['actionUrl']) //controler name and action name(function name)
        ->setMethod('post')
        ->setName('form');



        /*$this->setAttribs(array('horizontal'=> true,'method'=>'post'))
        ->setAction($options['actionUrl'])
        ->setName('Calendar');*/


        /* First Name*/
        $this->addElement("text", "txtName", array(
                "required" => true,
                "label" => "First Name",
                'filters' => array('StringTrim'),
                //              "size"=>"10",  
                'validators' => array(array('NotEmpty', true, array('messages' => 'Please enter first name')))));

        //Last Name
        $this->addElement("text", "txtLastName", array(
                "required" => true,
                "label" => "Last Name",
                'filters' => array('StringTrim'),               
                'validators' => array(array('NotEmpty', true, array('messages' => 'Please enter last name')))));

        //district... dropdown
        $district=new Application_Model_First();
        $disList=$district->getDistrictsList(); //obtain the list of districts from db.

        $this->addElement("select", "ddlDistrict", array(
                "required" => true,
                "label" => "District",
                'filters' => array('StringTrim'),           
                'MultiOptions'=>$disList,               
                'validators' => array(array('NotEmpty', true, array('messages' => 'Please enter district name')))));


        //Register button

        $this->addElement("submit", "Submit", array("label" => "Submit"));

    }   

}
```

Comment: activate the developer tools in chrome and look at what you are sending to the server within the browser !

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the variable $request, then calling $this->_request.

As it is with the same action all you need to do is call $request->isPost